# Why is there a need for a strong field versus weak field model? is the weak field just a simplified version, or is there a fundamental difference?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

If you explain by math, I would appreciate the full description of each variable.  But really, I am just looking for a conceptual understanding.  Newton's laws work for an apple falling from a tree branch or the Moon orbiting around the Earth, and so we called them universal laws.  Are the strong field relations "universal laws" that work everywhere, while weak field approximations are simpler but don't extrapolate well into heavy gravity fields?  Or is there something different about the heavy gravity fields that change the laws of nature, so that one can't use strong field equations in a weak field and vice versa?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take "strong (weak) field laws" to mean General Relativity (Newton's Law of Gravity). Newton's Law of gravity defines a universal force between all masses, given by the two mass expression:

$$ F =G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$$

It can be used to define a conservative field (called: gravity) defined by a potential:

$$ \vec g = -\nabla \Phi$$

which can be related to the density of matter:

$$ \nabla^2\Phi = \rho$$

This makes solving basic problems of ballistics, orbits, and gross interplanetary trajectories relatively easy.

Meanwhile, General Relativity is a geometric field theory of spacetime, in which the metric of spacetime, $g_{\mu\nu}$, is the field. The curvature of the metric is related to the stress-energy tensor, $T_{\mu\nu}$.

$$ G_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}$$

This is actually 10 coupled differential equations. Mass appears in the equation via $T_{tt}$, which is the energy density. The other components are energy flux, momentum change, stress, and pressure.

The 1st solution to these equations (a static Black hole) was found in a few years. The 2nd closed for solution (a rotating black hole) took another 40 years. They are very difficult to solve, and it has only become tractable with the advent of numerical relativity.

They only solve for the gravitation. Solving trajectory requires solving the geodesic equation:

$$\frac{d^2x^{\mu}}{ds^2}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{ds}
\frac{dx^{\beta}}{ds}$$

which is also, not trivial.

The good news is that in simple cases, like on the Earth, the geodesic equation reduces to Newtons Law of gravity.

So the weak field limit of GR *is* Newton's law of gravity, which are much easier to solve.

Newton's Law fails experimental tests when the field is strong, which is parameterized by the Schwarzschild radius:

$$r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2} $$

The Schwarzschild radius of the Earth is nine millimeters, which is 700 million times smaller than the radius. For the Sun, it's 3 km, or 233 thousand times smaller than it's actual radius. It's easier to observe relativistic effects near the Sun.

Newton's theory is non-relativistic, so it necessarily fails when trajectories are not small compared with the speed-of-light based on special relativity alone, but there are also velocity dependent gravitation effects, too.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring quantum effects, our current best theory of gravity is General Relativity (GR). GR is sufficient to explain **all** current observations involving gravity, including (but not limited to) observations involving weak gravitational fields.

However, doing calculations in GR can be quite cumbersome. Particularly in weak field situations, it is standard practice to use Newtonian gravity in place of GR, which is much simpler to work with, and is a very good approximation. Newtonian gravity can be shown to be equivalent to working to leading order in the gravitational field in GR, when the gravitational fields are weak.

Answer (score 1):

The weak field/slow speed solutions to Einstein's equations are useful for establishing the Newtonian limit, but pretty much eliminate the possibility of learning anything fun about GR!

You do *not* have to do both approximations together; there are a few articles that deal with the slow-speed/strong field scanario, which allows you to play with the Ricci tensor and scalar and the Energy-Momentum tensor in a more realistic "GR" environment.

The best example of this that I am aware of is Baez's [The Meaning of Einstein's Equation](https://math.ucr.edu/home//baez/einstein/). In particular, the section on [The Mathematical Details](https://math.ucr.edu/home//baez/einstein/node10.html).

Basically, it is the "high speed" part of GR the "explodes" the mathematics beyond simple analysis; the "high gravity" part is *very* accessible by comparison.

Comment: Thank you, I will need to go through that reference very carefully.  One problem I have is that I think in "common sense" physical terms.  I understand things like force, mass, velocity, etc., as would any member of the public.  I get as far as "flow of x-momentum" and "flow of t-momentum" and then I say, what is a flow of momentum?  What is t-momentum?  A second problem is the lack of numeric examples.  Like if a 5 kg object goes 10 m/s in the x-direction with acceleration of 1 m/s2, what numerically is the x-momentum flow and t-momentum flow?

Comment: That was one of the first good beginner's GR references I found.  I didn't understand any of the technical stuff, but the words were good enough to tide me over until I did.  You might find the overall tutorial here more useful: https://math.ucr.edu/home//baez/gr/ - Oz & the Wizard is a little different to the usual fare!  As for worked examples, they are not as easy to set up as you might think, or they would be all over the place ;)  Certainly not suitable for beginners!

Comment: Well, that's a shame.  I think that there are easier ways to solve general relativity problems, and I can certainly get results for things like proper time, fall paths, and so on, for any speed  up to lightspeed, and any gravity up to an event horizon.  But I don't know if those results are valid, and I don't know how to check them (other than a few examples, like planetary precession, gravity lensing, shapiro delay, photon sphere, and, of course, Newtonian stuff).   But for any problem not involving frame dragging, I have been able to match the few quantified results that I can find.

Comment: OK apologies I was a little unclear. There are two main aspects to GR: "spacetime tells matter how to move" is _relatively_ easy, and you can get useful results and check them with the literature.  I have done BH simulations myself and have checked 3D light & matter orbits against various papers.  "Matter tells spacetime how to curve" (like the Baez material) is much more difficult to handle, and that is what I have been referring to above , as I have recently got back into GR and started looking at things like geodesic congruences and various consequential things from that.